# How to select database name in sys.dm_*

Tags: sql, sql-server, system-tables

I'm calling stored proc through a service. I wanted my stored proc to be running on a database.
I've two questions

1. Is sys.dm_* tables specific to a database or it is general one?

```
select * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
```

Does above query return requests of all the databases or the current database where the query is being executed?

2. If sys.dm_* specific to a database is there any way to specify the database through stored procedure. I'm aware that we cannot use `use`. and `select * FROM [dbname].sys.dm_exec_requests` isn't working it seems. It returns the result for the current DB it seems. I may be wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `dm_*` tables are global to the system.  The statement `select * from [dbname].sys.dm_exec_requests` returns data for all databases on the server.  If the table contains database specific data, then it will include a `database_id` field.

If you want to limit the data your stored procedure returns to just one database, then you have to qualify by `database_id`.  Both of the following statements work in stored procedures:

```
/* specify the database name manually */
declare @db_name sysname = 'master'

select *
from   sys.dm_exec_requests er
       inner join sys.databases d on er.database_id = d.database_id
where  d.name = @db_name

/* gets the database name for the current database */
select *
from   sys.dm_exec_requests er
       inner join sys.databases d on er.database_id = d.database_id
where  d.name = db_name()
```